# php sizeof counting wrong with the if command

Tags: php

For some reason I'm trying to print spans if the size of $lines is whichever size. The size of $lines is 2.

```
 if (sizeof($lines) == 1){
             // Seasonal Price #1
             //preg_match('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $lines[0], $match);
             preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $lines[0], $match);
             $season_label = explode(":", $lines[0]);
             //print_r($season_label);
             $dollar_amount0 = $match[0][0];
             $dollar_amount01 = $match[0][1];
             $label = str_replace('<strong>', '', $season_label[0]);
             $label = str_replace('Adult', '', $label);
                     echo '<span class="head"><br/><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Seasonal / '; echo $label;echo': </span><span class="text-lg lh1em"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adult:';\
 echo$dollar_amount0; echo'</span>
                                                                                               <span class="text-lg lh1em"> / Children:'; echo $dollar_amount01; echo '</span>';

             }


             echo sizeof($lines); // size of lines is equal to 2, for some 
             reason it's not printing anything in between this if condition.

             if (sizeof($lines) == 2){
             echo "test"; //for some reason it prints "test"
             // Seasonal Price #2
             preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $lines[1], $match);
             $season_label = explode(":", $lines[1]);
             //print_r($season_label);
             $dollar_amount0 = $match[0][0];
             $dollar_amount01 = $match[0][1];
             $label = str_replace('<strong>', '', $season_label[0]);
             $label = str_replace('Adult', '', $label);
                     echo '<span class="head"><br/><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Seasonal / '; echo $label;echo': </span><span class="text-lg lh1em"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adult:';\
 echo$dollar_amount0; echo'</span>
                                                                                               <span class="text-lg lh1em"> / Children:'; echo $dollar_amount01; echo '</span>';
             }

             if (sizeof($lines) == 3){
             // Seasonal Price #3
             preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $lines[2], $match);
             $season_label = explode(":", $lines[2]);
             //print_r($season_label);
             $dollar_amount0 = $match[0][0];
             $dollar_amount01 = $match[0][1];
             $label = str_replace('<strong>', '', $season_label[0]);
             $label = str_replace('Adult', '', $label);
                     echo '<span class="head"><br/><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Seasonal / '; echo $label;echo': </span><span class="text-lg lh1em"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adult:';\
 echo$dollar_amount0; echo'</span>
                                                                                  <span class="text-lg lh1em"> / Children:'; echo $dollar_amount01; echo '</span>';
             }
```

echo sizeof($lines) is 2; for some reason it's not printing anything in between the second if condition.

Comment: sizeof works for arrays. are you sure lines variable is an array which could be more than 2 ?

Comment: What's the content of the variable $lines?

Comment: echo $lines; is an array.

Comment: contents of the $lines is  Array ( [0] => Special price for September 3-10 Adult: $2,699.00 Children: $2,025.00 
[1] => Special price for September 3-10 Adult: $2,699.00 Children: $2,025.00 
)

Comment: you're sure you got error-repoting on and the code posted is not 1:1 the original one? (the comment over two lines will throw a syntax error)

Comment: no errors, the page comes up.

Answer (score 0):

This runs just fine:

```
<?php

$lines = ['Special price for September 3-10 Adult: $2,699.00 Children: $2,025.00', 'Special price for September 3-10 Adult: $2,699.00 Children: $2,025.00'];

$template = '<span class="head"><br/><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Seasonal / {:label}: </span><span class="text-lg lh1em"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adult: {:amount2}</span><span class="text-lg lh1em"> / Children: {:amount1}</span>';

function format_string($line, $template)
{
    preg_match_all('/(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $line, $match);
    $season_label = explode(":", $line);
    //print_r($season_label);
    $dollar_amount0 = $match[0][0];
    $dollar_amount01 = $match[0][1];
    $label = str_replace('<strong>', '', $season_label[0]);
    $label = str_replace('Adult', '', $label);

    $params = [
        'label' => $label,
        'amount1' => $dollar_amount0,
        'amount2' => $dollar_amount01,
    ];

    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $template = str_replace('{:' . $key . '}', $value, $template);
    }

    return $template;
}

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo format_string($lines[0], $template);
}
```

Comment: does the content from both top 2 conditions print?

Comment: No, only one. `sizeof()` is the exact size. Perhaps you need something like `count($lines) < N`.

Comment: nope, the same issue, thanks but I still get the same result becuase the numbers are the same.

Comment: What's the result you are expecting? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: your code dosn't work either. i'm updating the loop that creates the lines.

Comment: echo count($lines); is equals to 2

Comment: the size of $lines is always 2.

Comment: Exactly! If you define an array with 2 elements, it's size will be 2 unless you modify it.

Comment: then why isn't the content from if (sizeof($lines) == 2){ isn't showing up, I'm sorry, I'm not being difficult, it's just not showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116846/discussion-between-fedeisas-and-unixmiah).

Comment: how is the line being modifies if nothing is added to it, and some reason echo "test" is showing up in the second if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm terribly sorry, I found the mistake. The issue was

```
if (count($lines) >= 1)
if (count($lines) >= 2)
if (count($lines) >= 3)
if (count($lines) >= 4)
```

It had to be greater or equals to 1, 2, 3, 4 otherwise the previous record wasn't going to print. I forgot the the order of operation, PEMDAS, fml!

The issue of the matter was not having `>=` therefore, nothing previously was printed. Thank you.